# How to write to a text file Javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I am attempting to write a webScrape to a text file and it just isn't working. All the text file says is object over and over again. Any help will be much appreciated, i am relatively new to this type of programming and i'm coming up blank!

EDIT: I now have the text file working but i'm wondering how i can to a line break after each line of data is added.

```
 const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const camelCase = require('camelcase'); // added this for readale properties
const fs = require('fs') 

// use async / await feature
async function scrape(url) {

    // get html page
    const { data } = await axios.get(url);

    // convert html string to cheerio instance
    const $ = cheerio.load(data);

    // query all list items
    return $('.tabular-data-panel > ul')
        // convert cheerio collection to array for easier manipulation
        .toArray()
        // transform each item into proper key values
        .map(list => $(list)
            // query the label element
            .find('.panel-row-title')
            // convert to array for easier manipulation
            .toArray()
            // use reduce to create the object
            .reduce((fields, labelElement) => {
                // get the cheerio instance of the element
                const $labelElement = $(labelElement);
                // get the label of the field
                const key = $labelElement.text().trim();
                // get the value of the field
                const value = $labelElement.next().text().trim();
                // asign the key value into the reduced object
                // note that we used camelCase() to make the property easy to read
                fields[camelCase(key)] = value;
                // return the object
                return fields;
            }, {})
        );

}

async function main() {
    const url = 'https://www.lseg.com/resources/1000-companies-inspire/2018-report-1000-companies-uk/search-1000-companies-uk-2018?results_per_page=100';
    const companies = await scrape(url);

    fs.writeFile('Output.txt', companies, (err) => { 

        if (err) throw err; 
        console.log('it/s done')
    })

    console.log(companies);
}



main();
```

Comment: well, scrape does return an array of objects - you could write `JSON.stringify(companies)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can find great instructions here:
[Javascript how to write data to file](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-program-to-write-data-in-a-text-file/)

The second try:

```
fs.writeFile('Output.txt', JSON.stringify(companies), (err) => { 

        if (err) throw err; 
        console.log('it/s done')
    })

    console.log(companies);
}
```

Because you can only write Strings to a text-file.

- edit -> not true, one can also use bytes etc. but in the end they are saved and processed like a string (eg. pdfs are byte based)

Answer (score 0):

the result of function `scrape(url)` seems to be like an array.
You can `JSON.stringify` the result to make it into string.
Or, you can also just use `join()`

```js
// ...
const companies = await scrape(url).then(data => JSON.stringify(data))
```

OR

```js
const companies = await scrape(url).then(data => data.join('\n'))
```